# TestNG Maven SeleniumGrid

Tags: java, maven, selenium

I have a maven project for a test case by using SeleniumGrid+testNG,

The problem is that I think I have everything well configured however when I try to run I always get an error:

Running com.pruebas.seleniumGridTestNG.dataDrivenParallelXML.TestLanzadorIdealistaTestNG
Configuring TestNG with: org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNGMapConfigurator@41fc2fb
Tests run: 4, Failures: 2, Errors: 0, Skipped: 2, Time elapsed: 0.597 sec <<< FAILURE!

I can't even see where the error is , because It's not on the test classes.

This is my POM file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>EjemploSeleniumGridMavenTestNG</groupId>
  <artifactId>EjemploSeleniumGridMavenTestNG</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>

      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.42.2</version>
    </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>6.3.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
        </dependencies>

</project>

<plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
        <configuration>
          <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/test-properties.xml</suiteXmlFile>
          </suiteXmlFiles>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
</plugins>
```

However I uploaded my project to Github just If someone wants to try it.

https://github.com/miguelavm84/EjemploSeleniumGridMavenTestNG

I'd appreciate your help, Thank you.

Comment: How are you running your tests?  `mvn test`?

Comment: Yes sircapsalot

I've also tried with "mvn test site"

Comment: I think you'll need some more dependencies.. take a look at http://github.com/ddavison/getting-started-with-selenium/blob/master/pom.xml   Regarding your issue though, i think it *might* be the `<scope>`.. remove the `<scope>test</scope>` on each of those dependencies

Comment: I keep getting the same sircapsalot :'( , I deleted the scope of test on the dependencies.